# Access NodeJS logs in server using pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, pm2

I recently deployed a node JS app to a debian server using Nginx and PM2.

Everything seems to be working fine, I can access the website from the link and port i specified in my nginx configuration.

In my app I save values to a database (using mongojs). While running this webpage everything seems to be fine but nothing is being saved to the database.
So i assumed i have an error in my nodeJS app.

I tried to access the logs of my nodejs app, I cleared the pm2 logs, went to my site URL again, and then I executed the command `pm2 logs` but couldn't see any logs at all.

I need to access the logs of my app (AKA the logs that are usually displayed when i manually write `node app.js` locally in the terminal).

Sorry i am new at this

Am i missing something?

My PM2 logs :

```
PM2        | [2018-05-14 13:21:56] PM2 error: Cancelling versioning data parsing
PM2        | [2018-05-14 13:21:56] PM2 log: App [app] with id [0] and pid [12345], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | [2018-05-14 13:21:56] PM2 log: pid=12345 msg=process killed
PM2        | [2018-05-14 15:34:32] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:app id:0
PM2        | [2018-05-14 15:34:32] PM2 log: App name:app id:0 online
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:31:27] PM2 log: Stopping app:app id:0
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:31:27] PM2 log: App [app] with id [0] and pid [12345], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:31:27] PM2 log: pid=12345 msg=process killed
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:32:59] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:app id:0
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:32:59] PM2 log: App name:app id:0 online
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:39:15] PM2 log: Stopping app:app id:0
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:39:15] PM2 log: App [app] with id [0] and pid [54321], exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:39:15] PM2 log: pid=54321 msg=process killed
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:39:41] PM2 log: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:app id:0
PM2        | [2018-05-15 13:39:41] PM2 log: App name:app id:0 online
```

My PM2 list:

```
App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user   │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ app      │ 0  │ fork │ 54321 │ online │ 12      │ 7m     │ 0%  │ 40.7 MB   │ user │ disabled │
```

Comment: Are you sure your app is running? `pm2 list` if it's in there, `pm2 logs` should work.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande It is present in `pm2 list` , the pm2 logs show only the events in pm2, what i need is to see the logging that i coded as `console.log()` in my app.js

Comment: `pm2 logs` shows your `console.log` output, why it isn't working for you I do not know with the information at hand

Comment: Can you show the output of `pm2 list` (Are you using sudo)?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande i updated my question and put them

Comment: `pm2 list` output, not `pm2 logs` (leave them, they're useful)

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande updated